# How to select from the drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Im working on Selenium and I want to Select from drop down using selenium Python. how can I select it. I want to select (00:00-06:00) from drop down

```html
<div class="prepopulated-select__SelectContainer-sc-xyhoe8-1 bfnzNQ">
<select class="prepopulated-select__Select-sc-xyhoe-2-3 kpVQsa" name="time">
<option class="prepopulated-select__StyledOption-sc-xyhoe8-2 lljkAc" value="0">00:00-06:00</option>
<option class="prepopulated-select__StyledOption-sc-xyhoe8-2 lljkAc" value="6">06:00-12:00</option>
<option class="prepopulated-select__StyledOption-sc-xyhoe8-2 lljkAc" value="12">12:00-18:00</option>
<option class="prepopulated-select__StyledOption-sc-xyhoe8-2 lljkAc" value="18">18:00-00:00</option></select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "prepopulated-select__SelectContainer-sc-xyhoe8-1 bfnzNQ"))
```

**select by visible text**

```
select.select_by_visible_text('00:00-06:00')
```

**select by value**

```
select.select_by_value('00:00-06:00')
```

Comment: Please accept the answer, if you think this has resolve your problem.